# call javascript function when binding

Tags: nativescript

I'm new in Nativescript.And how I call javascript function when binding? I try try like method below, but get empty result.

```
 <Repeater items="{{ Match }}">
       <Repeater.itemTemplate>
           <StackLayout>
              <Label  text="{{ SubStringMatch(MatchNo) }}" />
              <Label  text="{{ DateTime }}"  />
           </StackLayout>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
 </Repeater>



function SubStringMatch(value) {
   return value.substring(1);
}

exports.SubStringMatch= SubStringMatch;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, I believe, you are trying to convert a number value into a string. This could be achieved by using a converter function. You can read more about it in [{N} documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/bindings.html#using-converters-in-bindings).